# RecyclerView LayoutManager - force to keep a view even if not visible

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager, linearlayoutmanager

I am animating views between two `RecyclerView`. The first one is something like a list of folders showing the first item as cover, clicking it opens a new view showing the folders content animating the cover to the first item. Clicking back animates all visible views back to the folder where they came from (the cover being the top most view). This looks great as long as the opened folder shows the first item. If I scroll down the first item will be offscreen and the back animation does not look that good anymore because the cover view is not animated (I'm only animating all visible views currently).

What I think would work is following: the `LayoutManager` could position the first item at a position shortly offscreen and keeps it as a special view in it's pool so that u always can access the first view and when I animate back to the folder view I can animate the cover in addition to all other currently visible items ( the cover will be animated from top of the screen).

**This means I need following:**

- the `LayoutManager` must handle the first item as a special one that is not recycled (I may need it any time for the back animation)
- the first item must always be layed out (either at the default position in the list, if it is visible or offscreen directly above the screen), again because I may need it at any time for the back animation

Can someone help me where to start here? I think this is possible with extending the `LayoutManager` but I don't know where to start...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

```
recView.getRecycledViewPool().setMaxRecycledViews(TYPE_XXXX, 0);
```